# Which compiler flags are optimal for the Intel C Compiler on AMD FX 8350?

Tags: c, icc, amd-processor

I would like to use the Intel C Compiler due to its superior vectorization abilities. However, it understandably has no `-march=bdver2` flag which is what I would use on gcc for my AMD FX-8350 CPU.  It does have `-xavx` but I am not sure what other flags to use.

What are the optimal compiler flags for the AMD FX-8350 CPU using the Intel C Compiler?

`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep flags` gives:

> flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
>   pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt
>   pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid
>   aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt
>   aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a
>   misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce
>   nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall
>   bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid
>   decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold

Comment: none, obviously

Comment: @user3528438 Why none ?